# ArcGIS 10 - FLEXnet / lmtools

Tags: arcgis-license-manager

I got a tool for ArcGIS which has its own license manager (lmtools / flexnet). Everything is working fine.

My problem is:
When i use ArcGIS and start the tool the license is in use. Ok. When i stop the tool the license is still in use until i restart ArcGIS.

Is there any way (with a script or workaround) to tell the licensemanager: 
*"Hey i finished working, somone else can use it now"*

Its annoying to restart ArcGIS everytime :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FlexNet has the management utility "lmutil" which can be used for forcing license check-in (lmremove).

The general command scheme is:

```
lmutil lmremove -c LicenseFile.lic <feature> <user> <host> <display>
```

or

```
lmutil lmremove -c LicenseFile.lic -h <feature> <LM_Server> <port> <handle>
```

I think you need the license file to make things work, so try it with and possibly also without the -c parameter. Should look something like this.

```
lmutil lmremove -c LicenseFile.lic ARC/INFO GEOGEO GEOGEOsMachine "#2L\w {O"
```

or like this

```
lmutil lmremove -h ARC/INFO licenseserver 27000 305
```

You get these infos by using lmutil's lmstat command

```
lmutil lmstat -a -c <port>@<host>
```

As this works slightly different with different versions of FlexLM, you have to try should take a look in lmutils command reference on your installation.

EDIT: FlexNET uses Port numbers 27000 to 27005 by default, you can find out which one is living, by calling "netstat -a" on the server machine.

Comment: Thx i will try it

Answer (score 2):

It's old but interesting. Hit this one by accident.

This is a problem with the license manager, probably upgrading it, will solve the issue.

A user of floating license should close it, when not in use. If this is not happening, OpenLM provides this functionality, it closes the idle session and releases the license back to the license pool, automatically. Check for more information if www.openlm.com.

One can also use alllicenseparser.com to parse his FLEXlm debug log online and get detailed information about usage patterns.

Oren